# Undefined variable: request in sub method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to get all the records that have a relation to the category table, where the category_definition_id is the search input, I cannot access the $request->category variable in the sub method. It is in Laravel 5.5. Any ideas?

```
public function jobopenings(Request $request)
{
  $category_definitions = Category_definition::all();
  $skill_definitions = Skill_definition::all();

  $ads = new Ad;

  // Search for a user based on their name.
  if ($request->has('category')) {

    $ads = $ads->whereHas('categories', function($query){
        $query->where('category_definition_id', $request->category);
      });
  }

  $ads = $ads->where('type','1')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(15);

    return View::make('jobs')
    ->with('ads', $ads)
    ->with('category_definitions',$category_definitions)
    ->with('skill_definitions', $skill_definitions)
    ->with('ad_type','1');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare it using `use($request)`:

```
$ads = $ads->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($request) {
           $query->where('category_definition_id', $request->category);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `use` clause:

```
$ads = $ads->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('category_definition_id', $request->category);
    });
}
```